# LineCollection animation when updating the frames in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The following code supposed to do the same thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053964/animation-based-on-only-updating-colours-in-a-plot) where lines colours are updated during an animation. However, the colour is not being updated. Which part of this code is wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.animation as animation

lines = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        lines.append([(0, i), (1, j)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
col = LineCollection(lines, array=colors, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.add_collection(col)
ax.autoscale()

ims = []
for i in range(100):
    colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
    col.set_array(colors)
    ims.append([ax.add_collection(col)])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=200, blit=True,repeat_delay=10000)
plt.show()
```

The output I get from the above code is below
[image: code output]

Comment: what do you mean with "FuncAnimation doesn't help"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to draw the changed artist (your `LineCollection`) just after the line

```
col.set_array(colors)
```

You need to do this because the LineCollection was first added to the axes with the line

```
ax.add_collection(col)
```

and then it is changed in the loop. You must then update the figure. The simplest way to do this is by calling `plt.draw()` just before the line

```
im=ax.add_collection(col)
```

This however replots everything, and slows done a lot the animation. The solution is to draw first all the rest with a call to `plt.draw()` before the loop, and then updating only the changed artist with a call to `ax.draw_artist(col)`. The resulting code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.animation as animation

lines=[]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        lines.append([(0, i), (1, j)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
col = LineCollection(lines, array=colors, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.add_collection(col)
ax.autoscale()


ims=[]
plt.draw()
for i in range(100):
    col = LineCollection(lines,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
    col.set_array(colors)
    ax.draw_artist(col)
    im=ax.add_collection(col)
    ims.append([im])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=25, blit=True,repeat_delay=10000)
plt.show()
```

It is less tricky to do the same thing using `FuncAnimation()`, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077477/animate-a-line-with-different-colors), but you said you don't want to use it for some reasons.

Comment: Why did you use `array` and `set_array` over `colors` and `set_color`?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but its so dumb. I have to create the same package of lines again:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.animation as animation

lines=[]
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        lines.append([(0, i), (1, j)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
col = LineCollection(lines, array=colors, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.add_collection(col)
ax.autoscale()


ims=[]
for i in range(100):
    col = LineCollection(lines,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
    colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
    col.set_array(colors)
    im=ax.add_collection(col)
    ims.append([im])
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, ims, interval=25, blit=True,repeat_delay=10000)
plt.show()
```

I would be happy if somebody gives a me a solution without renewing the lines but only updating the colours.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of "LineCollection" we can set the individual color of each segment by using the method "set_color" and providing a sequence of rgba tupels:

*c : color or list of colors*

*Single color (all patches have same color), or a
sequence of rgba tuples; if it is a sequence the patches will
cycle through the sequence.*

The following code should work properly. It is using FuncAnimation though.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import matplotlib.animation as animation

lines = []
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        lines.append([(0, i), (1, j)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = np.random.random(len(lines))
col = LineCollection(lines, array=colors, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
ax.add_collection(col)
ax.autoscale()

def update(num, collection):
    colors = [(c, c, c) for c in np.random.random(len(lines))]
    collection.set_color(colors)
    return collection,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, 100, fargs=[col], interval=25, blit=True)
plt.show()
```