# Animating a time-dependent LineCollection using matplotlib

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, animation

As stated above, I am trying to animate a set of data that varies over time (position). I would like my graph to only show the position data but animate the position history over time. I have started with this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077477/animate-a-line-with-different-colors), and got it working. Now, instead of the whole line animating, I would like for the line to be drawn from left to right. I also need the line to be colored relative to a secondary set of data, which I have been able to accomplish with a LineCollection.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))

line = LineCollection([], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
line.set_array(np.linspace(0, 2, 1000))
ax.add_collection(line)

x = np.linspace(0, 2, 10000)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x))

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_segments([])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i, xss, yss, line):
    xs = xss[:i]
    ys = yss[:i]
    points = np.array([xs, ys]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
    line.set_segments(segments)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=[x, y, line], init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20)
plt.show()
```

I create a basic sine wave data set and again would like to animate the line being drawn from left to right. Right now, the LineCollection is being colored by the y-value of the line at the current x-position. Eventually, this will be a position data set pulled from a .csv file.

Finally, the issue. The code above runs without errors, however the line is not being drawn. I can see in my debugger that the `xs` and `ys` arrays are being added to during each step so that syntax *seems* to be working, just the updated LineCollection is not being displayed.

I am working on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, the line you're plotting is just very small. This is because the function you animate is given by

```py
x = np.linspace(0, 2, 10000)  # Note that `num=10000`
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x))
```

which has 10000 points, but you only animate the first 200 points.

```py
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(..., frames=200, interval=20)
```

## Easy fix

```py
num_frames = 200
x = np.linspace(0, 2, num_frames)
...
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(..., frames=num_frames, interval=20)
```

Comment: Yep that was it. I  also realized that i could see the line at 200 frames, but it was animating much slower than I thought it would so I wasn't even waiting long enough for it to really animate anything. Thanks!